# PyTorch - How to index an array of shape [2, 160, 12, 1024] using an array of shape [160] to get [2, 160, 1024]?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a tensor `A` of shape [2, 160, 12, 1024]. I have another tensor `B` of shape [160] where the values are between 0 to 11 e.g. [0,11,3,2,1,2,6,7,...]

I am trying to use `B` to index `A` along the **THIRD** axis it such that the output is [2, 160, 1024] e.g.

```
C = np.zeros((2,160,1024))
for i in range(160):
    C[:,i,:] = A[:,i,B[i],:]
```

`A[:,B]` does not work because it ends up indexing along the second axis. The solution using for loops is slow because I have a significantly larger array.

Answer (score 0):

```
C = A[:, torch.arange(A.shape[1]), B]
```